# Scrollable Grid (Yahoo email like)

Tags: grid, scrollbar

I was wondering if anyone knew of a scrollable gridview control that works similar to the yahoo email gridview.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery I recommend [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

There is a nice grid component in [extjs](http://extjs.com/) too.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to guess, I'd say it's a highly customized [YUI DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/), so that might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are looking for ASP.NET AJAX grid solution with yahoo-like scrolling, the Telerik grid may give you Yahoo-like deferred scrolling. Check out [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/virtualscrollpaging/defaultcs.aspx) on their site.

Dick

Answer (score 0):

DHX's [dhtmlxGrid control](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml) will do that as well.  The basic edition is free.

They've got examples with 50,000 records, [with](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/loading_big_datasets/50000_paging.html) and [without paging](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/loading_big_datasets/50000.html).